# Saddlepoint approximation when CGF is approximated

Tags: options, moments

According to the saddlepoint approximation, if the cumulant generating function $K(t) = \log E[e^{tX}]$ of the distribution of the random variable $X$ exists and is known, then the density $f(x)$ of $X$ can be approximated as follows:
$$
f(x) \approx \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi K''(\hat t(x))}} \exp\{K( \hat t(x)) - \hat t(x) x \}
$$
where $\hat t(x)$ is the solution to $K'(\hat t(x)) = x$. Primes denote differentiation wrt $t$.

Now suppose the CGF is not known but approximated
$$
\tilde K(t) \approx \sum_{n=1}^4 \frac{\tilde \kappa_n}{n!} t^n
$$
Then I don't think there is always a unique and real solution to
$$
\tilde K'(\hat t(x)) = x
$$
which is a $3$-rd order polynomial equation, such that
$$
\tilde K''(\hat t(x)) > 0
$$

Are there `regularization' methods to ensure the approximated CGF has a proper valid region?

I am not sure otherwise what the applicability is of the saddlepoint method, at least in options pricing, if you cannot use an approximated CGF since many times the CGF is unknown.

**Background to my question**

If the skew is generated by a stoch vol model, I have found a way (actually years ago already) how to turn the skew into an approximately symmetric smile that respects the distribution of realized volatility.

Once I have this smile I can estimate the moments (and thus the cumulants) of realized volatility. For various values of correlation up to say $\pm 0.4$ I see that the estimated first four moments are quite stable, i.e. doesn't vary wildly with correlation which is how it should be.

Under this smile I can then in principle use the Hull and White mixing formula to approximate the distribution of realized volatility by assuming for example the CGF I wrote above.

I've tried estimating the density of realized vol using Gram-Charlier/Edgeworth as well, but those methods appear to be unstable.